# Get actual target table insert count

Tags: hive

I'm inserting data into hive external table in append mode. Every time I insert some records in a table, I want to get the count of actual records which are inserted into the hive external table. Is there any way I could find this information in any hive log file?

Comment: Did you get the answer? Can you post it if you did?

Answer (score -1):

There can be workaround for this. Not sure about any hive property for this.

- Have an additional timestamp column in your table.
- Do self join on table on timestamp column.
- count the latest records inserted into table. You can check below sample query:-

`SELECT count(1) from  (
SELECT tbl_alias.* FROM test_table tbl_alias JOIN
( select max(timestamp_date) as max_timestamp_date FROM  test_table) max_timestamp_date_table ON
tbl_alias.timestamp_date=max_timestamp_date_table.max_timestamp_date ) outer_table;`

Comment: As per your  suggestion , you are using a select query to calculate rows in sert. Think of a situation where the no of records are in millions.In that case it is not feasible to use select query everytime  as it would shoot up the ETL time. Im looking for a log file where I can get the no of  records inserted which would be time saving.